# Does anyone know the word that built-in function ord() abbreviate for?

Tags: python, function, built-in

python has a built-in function `ord()`, I think it must be a anbbreviation. Just like another built-in function `chr()`, which is an abbreviation of the word "character". Does anyone know the word that built-in function `ord()` abbreviate for?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's an abbreviation for "ordinal". *Ordinal numbers* are counting numbers -- i.e., 1, 2, 3. `ord()` converts the character into its (countable) position in the character set.